# Contact.PHP Form Internal Server error

Tags: php, html, server, web

I am trying to send form data from my contact.php page using PHPMailer. But it is not working properly.  It is showing internal server error.

This is my contact.php form code. Can you see what is wrong with this code.

```
<?PHP

session_start();
$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];

require_once("/home/leasingexpertzz/public_html/helpers/security.php");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
   <head>
      <title>Contact</title>
     <?PHP include "header.php"; ?>
   </head>
   <body class="size-1140">

      <!-- TOP NAV WITH LOGO -->  
      <header>
         <?PHP include "nav.php"; ?>
      </header>
      <section>
         <div id="head">
            <div class="line">
               <h1>Leasing Expertz</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="content" class="left-align contact-page">
             <h1 class="sub-title">Reach us</h1>
            <div class="line">
               <div class="margin">
                  <div class="s-12 l-6">
                     <h2>Leasing Expertz</h2>
                     <address>
                        <p><i class="icon-home icon"></i> Plot no. P-25 1st floor, Uppal South End, Near  Eldico Mentions.</p>
                        <p><i class="icon-globe_black icon"></i> Sohna Road, Gurugram, Haryana, India</p>
                        <p><i class="icon-mail icon"></i> leasingexpertzz@gmail.com</p>
                     </address>
                     <br />
                     <h2>Social</h2>
                     <p class="fb"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Leasing-Expertz-292379364250588/"><i class="icon-facebook icon"></i>Leasing Expertz</a></p>
                     <p class="linkedin"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><i class="icon-linked_in icon"></i>Linked In</a></p>
                     <p class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="icon-twitter icon"></i>Tweeter</a></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="s-12 l-6">
                     <h2>Write to us</h2>
                     <form class="customform" method="post" action="email.php">
                        <div class="s-12 l-7"><input name="senderEmail" placeholder="Your e-mail" title="Your e-mail" type="text" <?PHP echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?> />
                        <?PHP if(!empty($errors)) : ?>
                         <p> <?PHP echo implode('', $errors); ?></p>
                        <?PHP endif;?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="s-12 l-7"><input name="sender" placeholder="Your name" title="Your name" type="text" <?PHP echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>/>
                        <?PHP if(!empty($errors)) : ?>
                        <p> <?PHP echo implode('', $errors); ?></p>
                        <?PHP endif;?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="s-12 l-7"><input name="senderPhone" placeholder="Your phone number" title="Your Phone" type="text" <?PHP echo isset($fields['phone']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['phone']) . '"' : '' ?>/>
                        <?PHP if(!empty($errors)) : ?>
                        <p> <?PHP echo implode('', $errors); ?></p>
                        <?PHP endif;?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="s-12"><textarea placeholder="Your massage" name="message" rows="5" <?PHP echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?>></textarea>
                        <?PHP if(!empty($errors)) : ?>
                        <p> <?PHP echo implode('', $errors); ?></p>
                        <?PHP endif;?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4"><button type="submit">Submit Button</button></div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- MAP -->   
         <div id="map-block">      
               <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3508.9917339135745!2d77.03635061456353!3d28.419506282502333!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x390d229e71ef44dd%3A0x9931b80f30d32dd3!2sJMD+Megapolis!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1492751226145" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- FOOTER -->   
      <footer>
         <?PHP include "footer.php"; ?>
      </footer>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>   
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
           $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            slideSpeed : 300,
            autoPlay : true,
            navigation : false,
            pagination : false,
            singleItem:true
           });
           $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
            slideSpeed : 300,
            autoPlay : true,
            navigation : false,
            pagination : true,
            singleItem:true
           });
         });   

      </script> 
   </body>
</html>

<?PHP
 unset($_SESSION['errors']);
 unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

Below is my email.php for PHPMailer.

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("/home/leasingexpertzz/public_html/PHPMailer_5.2.0/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$errors =[];
if(isset($_POST["senderEmail"], $_POST["sender"], $_POST["senderPhone"], $_POST["message"])){

    $fields = [
        'email'=> $_POST["senderEmail"], 
        'name' => $_POST["sender"], 
        'phone' => $_POST["senderPhone"], 
        'message' => $_POST["message"]
    ];

    foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[] = 'The' . $field . 'is required.';
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();            // set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "admin@leasingexpert.co.in";  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxx"; // SMTP password

        $mail->From = "admin@leasingexpert.co.in";
        $mail->FromName = "Leasing Expert";

        $mail->AddAddress("admin@leasingexpert.co.in");                  // name is optional

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters

        $mail->IsHTML();                                  // set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
        $mail->Body    = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . '(' . $fields['email'] . ')' . $fields['phone'] . '<p>' . $fields['message'] .. '</p>';

        if($mail->Send())
        {
           header("Location: http://leasingexpert.co.in/confirmation.php");
           die();
        }
        else{
            $errors[] = 'Message could not be sent.';
        }

        header("Location: http://leasingexpert.co.in/confirmation.php");

    }

}else{
    $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;    

?>
```

Comment: Wee need to know what errors you see. If you don't see any on the page, what do they say in your error log? While developing you might want to look into showing errors by default http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/601299

Comment: Fatal error:  Call to undefined function session_starts() in /home/leasingexpertzz/public_html/email.php on line 3

Comment: No error message coming anymore and a blank page is opening on submitting.

Comment: Is confirmation.php empty? If it worked it might be worth just outputting some junk at the top of that file to make sure.

Comment: Thanks all. It is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try reading the logs, which can be in different places depending on your OS and the server you're using (apache, nginx...).

You could also use xdebug

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Error messages indicate that something, in general, is wrong in programming.

While developing you have to enable to error log in PHP.ini file.

Then you can easily find out the error[enter link description here](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938)

Comment: I am actually doing it on webhosting and I have error.log file